# How to force user to click a button in only one active window and not be able to click things in other windows?

Tags: delphi

I have a small question.

I think there must be a easy way to do it but I just can't find the keyword, so please teach me.

---

Here is the question:

For example, default ShowMessage pops a window with 'OK' button, then program stops temporarily before you click 'OK'.

This makes sense, but the problem is, you can still interact with other objects before you click 'OK'.

It certainly causes some problems like this:

```
var
  Count: Integer; //initial it to 1

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Count));
  Inc(Count);
end;
```

By not closing the message box, program always stops at same place and the variable remains the same.

How do I lock the popping window so you can't interact with other objects?(System forces you to turn your focus back to the popping window if you do so)

Is it possible to achieve this with ShowMessage?

---

It would be helpful if I can get some tips.

Thanks a lot.

---

Edit:
Using the unit  QDialogs.ShowMessage version causes a non-modal problem. Beware of those units you are not familiar lol.

Comment: Use Application.MessageBox, AFAIR it has an option to be modal (or even application-modal).

Comment: If the dialog is "modal" you cannot interact with other objects.

Comment: @Spook ShowMessage is modal. No need for Application.MessageBox.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wrote in Delphi a long while ago, forgotten some things :) Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShowMessage shows a modal dialog. In other words, it disables its owning window while the dialog shows. And so you cannot interact with the other windows in your app. ShowMessage already does what you want.

If you find that you can interact with other windows in your application whilst the dialog is showing, then you must have got the window ownership wrong.

Comment: I know my problem now. Trying to fix it. Thank you:)

Comment: Need help. I see the problem but I dont see how to fix it. I use ShowMessage in same form, what else do I need?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything. What did you do? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Uh...I do nothing. Does it matter if part of my text in ShowMessage come from other units?

Comment: No. Start from an empty VCL forms app and see that ShowMessage is modal. Then work out why your app differs.

Comment: Start form an empty VCL forms works. I add two buttons and test it. But it broke when I do exactly the same thing on my project...trying to find out why

Comment: I think I've found the problem. QDialogs will cause this problem. I don't know how but it does. Problem solved for now. Thanks for Your Patience:)

Comment: Presumably for ended up calling the ShowDialog from QDialogs.